# How can one automatically logon to multiple user accounts in Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, login

We are running a Windows 2008 R2 Terminal Server. Currently, we have local admin accounts created, one for each client that runs our software (SiteA, SiteB, etc). We need these user accounts to auto logon if the server is rebooted. The accounts need to run a full user environment, as we will login remotely at times via TeamViewer to check processes and makes changes, etc.

We are using the Registry Hack method now, but that only allows one account to logon. I've seen a program called LogonExpert, but I've never heard of it so I don't know how trust worthy it is, etc. Is there any other way to auto logon to multiple accounts in our environment? Currently the users are local users, but we could make them domain users if that is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to change user account settings.

- Go to Start Button and type Run
- Type control userpasswords2
- Clear the tick box on "users must enter a username and password to use this computer"

If you are doing on a server, the message will not appear. You need to change some registry values.

- Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
- Edit these values

  - AutoAdminLogon  1
  - DefaultUserName A username to be used for automatic logon
  - DefaultPassword The password for the username
  - ForceAutoLogon  1

As soon as you change the AutoAdminLogon to 1, then you will see the tick box with message under the User Accounts settings.

For more information, please have a look at this page. http://www.expta.com/2008/04/how-to-enable-autologon-for-windows.html

Another solution would be using AutoLogon tool https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb963905.aspx